# How do I get rid of the NaN error when converting temperature with a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make a JS Fahrenheit to Celsius converter, and for some reason whenever I input a number and that goes through the function, it spits back out a `NaN` where the Temperature is supposed to go.

Edit: Added in the "value" after the "ftemp" and "ctemp"

Edit: I deleted the values in the ftemp and ctemp and instead tried to access them in the function itself just like two people answered, and it works fine now.

```js
function ftoc(ft) {
  c = ft * (9 / 5) + 32;
  return c;
}

function ctof(ct) {
  f = (c - 32) / (9 / 5);
  return f;
}
button1 = document.getElementById("ftempsubmit");
button2 = document.getElementById("ctempsubmit");
fvalue = document.getElementById("ftemp").value;
cvalue = document.getElementById("ctemp").value;
fpopup = document.getElementById("fpopup");
cpopup = document.getElementById("cpopup");

button1.onclick = function() {
  cpopup.value = ftoc(fvalue);
};

button2.onclick = function() {
  fpopup.value = ctof(cvalue);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ftemp" placeholder="Enter F" />
<button id="ftempsubmit">Submit F</button>
<br />
<br />
<input id="cpopup" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id="ctemp" placeholder="Enter C" />
<button id="ctempsubmit">Sumbit C</button>
<br />
<br />
<input id="fpopup" />
```

Comment: Try `ftoc(Number(fvalue))`

Comment: You're trying to do the math with element references. Now, after edit, consider the value you're reading, ex. into `fvalue`, at the time the script is executed. Read the values inside the event handler, then they're up to date.

Comment: You edited your code after you posted the question and added in the code that was missing so it fixed many of the problems - I put your new code into a snippet and you can see it working. If you have a specific error, please edit the question to tell us so that we are not fixing ones that are non-existent any more.

Comment: Yes FluffyKitte, I apologize, I'm new to StackOverflow and this was my first question so I'm still getting used to how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the actual `value` of the inputs but rather the HTML element to your function which will throw `NaN`

I have also change the `type=text` to `type=number` as you will using `integer` only for `conversion`.

In your function `ctof` you are getting argument at `ct` but you are using `c` only when doing the calculation which mean it will throw an error of `c` not defined.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function ftoc(ft) {
  var c = ft * (9 / 5) + 32;
  return c;
}

function ctof(ct) {
  var f = (ct - 32) / (9 / 5);
  return f;
}

button1 = document.getElementById("ftempsubmit");
button2 = document.getElementById("ctempsubmit");
fvalue = document.getElementById("ftemp");
cvalue = document.getElementById("ctemp");
fpopup = document.getElementById("fpopup");
cpopup = document.getElementById("cpopup");

button1.onclick = function() {
  cpopup.value = ftoc(+fvalue.value);
};

button2.onclick = function() {
  fpopup.value = ctof(+cvalue.value);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="ftemp" placeholder="Enter F" />
  <button id="ftempsubmit">Submit F</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input id="cpopup" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="number" id="ctemp" placeholder="Enter C" />
  <button id="ctempsubmit">Sumbit C</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input id="fpopup" />
  <br />
  <br />

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The OP changes their question and added in those missing `.value`s - it got me too, I was about to post an answer with the same when I saw that. So I checked their new code and now there's nothing wrong anymore!

Comment: @FluffyKitten Sure. Thanks but were other errors which i have fixed.

Comment: Just letting you know so you can edit that part of your answer :)